# android security at lower api levels

Tags: java, android, api, cryptography, base64

I know that `android.utils.Base64` is only available as of API level8, but I've also heard of this Bouncy Castle Base64(`org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64`).

Is this part of the android jar?

and if so what API level is it for?

Finally at what API is `javax.crypto.*` first used in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an Android API, but you can take it from here: http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html

Comment: went for (this)[http://www.source-code.biz/base64coder/java/] one instead. Seemed to have a lot in common with the one in later versions of the android api.